# Firefox is not processing keyCode's. It displays the variables as a matrices in debugger

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

This code works perfectly on other browser such as Edge and Chrome, but for some reason Firefox does not want to detect the values from keyCode.

Notes: I used the debugger, and the when I pressed fore example '2', it keychar should have been 2 on the debugger watch list, but instead it gave me a wierd matrices symbol "[00]"

What it does: Prevents user from entering any characters that aren't numbers 0-9

Here's my code:

```
function keyHandlerForID(e)
{
    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
    if(keychar < '0' || keychar > '9')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function start()
{
    document.getElementById("studentID").addEventListener("keypress", keyHandlerForID, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
```

...

Like I said this is my script, but it works on all browsers but Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `which` or `charCode` property:

```
function keyHandlerForID(e)
{
    var keycode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
    if(keychar < '0' || keychar > '9')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    console.info(e, keycode, keychar)
}
```